# How to detect when an activity is launched ( Android Jelly Bean )

Tags: java, android, multithreading, optimization

**What I want to do :** I'm making an app which track app usage like many apps in Play Store does .

I have searched for a while a method to resolve it but I didn't found a useful answer .

- I know that there's no `Receiver` which detects app launch .
- I tried to use `Logcat` with filtering `ActivityManager` but unfortuneltly I assumed that Android has blocked SDK app access to the `READ_LOGS` permission in Jelly Bean .

**I found a solution for this problem but it's not optimized :** I declared a new `Thread` which works with a `Service` , I maked this `Thread` sleeps for x milliseconds and for each run I maked a test for running Activities and based on this I tracked Activity time launch ( with a low precision ) .

When I tried this I found it wasting a lot of CPU time, RAM, and battery life .

**Problem :** Is there a more efficient and optimized solution ? If yes please explain it If no , how does apps on Play Store ( like BreakFree, Menthal ... ) track app usage with a nice precision ?

---

Thanks in advance , It will be appreciated to find some useful solutions .

Comment: you can do that by checking specific **PID**

Comment: @maven thanks for comment , please can you more explain ?

Answer (score 0):

You need a service, something that will run in the background constantly. Than have your service do check for specific **PID** (process id).

As every application has its own process id, one can get it by

```
int id= android.os.Process.myPid();
```

Listen for the android.intent.action.MAIN also with the category android.intent.category.LAUNCHER. Then have that broadcast receiver override the onReceive method and do check to see the name of the application or process.

Then make conditions according to the need.

regards

Comment: Thanks for the answer , I'm gonna try it :)

Comment: then do upvote and accept my answer, it will encourage me to give more answers to the needy :)

Comment: please are you sure that we can listn to the android.intent.action.MAIN with a broadcast receiver , when I tried it it doesn't works and I found this https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/2Jz-AltxRjM